# How to rewrite the nonlinear matrix inequality as a linear one?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices, linear-matrix-inequality

Let $t>0$ be a scalar, $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric positive-definite matrix, and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ for some integers $n$ and $m$. I have the matrix inequality $tP^2-B B^\top \ge 0 $ and I want to make it linear with respect to $P$ and $B$. Using Schur compliment, I have
$$tP^2-B B^\top \ge 0 \Leftrightarrow  \begin{bmatrix}tP^2 & B \\ B^\top & I_{m\times m}\end{bmatrix} \ge 0.$$ But I do not know how to transform it to avoid the $P^2$ term. Any ideas?

**Update:** I also have some other LMIs involving $P$ and $B$, thus I cannot redefine $W:=P^2$ and solve an LMI for $W$.

Comment: Which terms are known and unknown? From your problem formulation it seems that $t$ is known and $P$ and $B$ are unknown, is this correct?

Comment: $t$ is known, $P$ and $B$ are the decision variables also constrained by other LMIs.

Comment: Do you have a solution now for this? I have a similar problem and I want to know what works.

Comment: @Acad Sorry, nope

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your initial matrix inequality linear in both $P$ and $B$, one could introduce an intermediate symmetric positive definite variable $X$, such that your initial matrix inequality can also be written as

$$
t\,X \ge t\,P^2 \ge B\,B^\top. \tag{1}
$$

This nested inequality is equivalent to the following two inequalities

$$
X \ge P^2 \Leftrightarrow  \begin{bmatrix}X & P \\ P & I\end{bmatrix} \ge 0, \tag{2a}
$$

$$
t\,X \ge B\,B^\top \Leftrightarrow  \begin{bmatrix}t\,X & B \\ B^\top & I\end{bmatrix} \ge 0. \tag{2b}
$$

Comment: Sorry, but you have $X\ge P^2$ and $X \ge B^\top B$. It does not imply that $P^2\ge B^\top B$, right? We need $P^2 \ge X$.

Comment: @Arastas You are correct. However, I do not quickly see a way of writing $P^2 \geq X$ as a LMI.

Comment: @Arastas the inequality direction would flip if you would use the inverses of $X$ and $P$ which would allow you to essentially use $(2a)$. Only this does introduce even more intermediate variables, such as $Y=X^{-1}$ which would be equivalent to $Y-Y\,X\,Y\leq0$ and $Y-Y\,X\,Y\geq0$ using their Schur complement, though some LMI solvers might have trouble with this (since you are essentially solving an equality instead of inequality) so there might be more elegant ways of solving this.

Comment: @Arastas Never mind my previous comment, I forgot about the matrix inverse when  using Schur's complement, which essentially turns the associated LMI into $$\begin{bmatrix}Y & Y \\ Y & Y\end{bmatrix}\geq0.$$ One could use $Y - I\,Y\,I\geq0$ and $X - I\,X\,I\geq0$, but those two are equivalent and their combination does not ensure $Y=X^{-1}$.